# Check SerialPort state effectively

Tags: c#, serial-port, task

I work with `SerialPort` and have necessity of react to it`s state (there is custom indicator of data reading by port).
I created that construction:

```
this.connectionWatcher = new Task(async () =>
{
    while (!this.cancelReceive.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        if ((this.port == null || !this.port.IsOpen) && this.machineState.IsConnected)
            this.machineState.IsConnected = false;
        if (this.port != null && this.port.IsOpen && !this.machineState.IsConnected)
            this.machineState.IsConnected = true;

        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}, this.cancelReceive.Token);
```

There is `machineState.IsConnected` is a `property` of `bool` which used in indicator.

I have 2 problems (rather, both can be solved simultaneously, imho):

1. When I close main window of app, this `Task` not stopped;
2. How to do it more effectively, because `while` is not a best practice and has big influence at CPU.

Comment: _"...while is not a best practice and has big influence at CPU..."_ - whilst it is not a best practice, in your case it _won't have a big influence on CPU due to your `Task.Delay`.  Now whether you should be doing the latter is an entirely new question

Comment: ...adding to my last comment, subscribing to `PinChanged` event is much more graceful to detect changes to say DSR and CTS than looping about with `while` and `Task.Delay()`.  Not entirely sure why you want logic just for `IsOpen`, that's pretty trivial.  No loop required

Comment: When it starting, CPU`s load increases in task manager

Comment: Opening a COM port is trivial.  Why are you getting increased CPU load?

Comment: I don`t know, in my opinion it is because while loop is used.

Comment: It's easily settled.  Comment out the `Task.Delay()` and watch the CPU usage increase significantly

Comment: `PinChanged` does not work...

Comment: Guess you better lodge a ticket with Microsoft